# External images not showing in listview for some people

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.forms

This is a really peciular issue that only seems to be affecting .1%> of our users. But an issue nonetheless. An issue I am unable to reproduce or provide any kind of log/output for, considering it's not a crash or an error. We have a grid page which utilizes a list view. Inside the listview, we have an image which source is external and gets set in the `OnBindingContextChange` method in the viewcell implementation. The app works fine for most users, however some have been reporting images not showing at all. None of them. The listview must still be working fine, since they see ads (of course). But they say images are not appearing. I was able to contact 3 of the users it was happening to, and was also able to get them on Test Flight where I can upload builds with variations of code to see if we can find the culprit.

Here's what I've tried:

- We implemented code in our listview to work around a xamarin bug, in which, lets say you have 1 image in each row. If you scroll down the page fast enough, you'll see images from previous cells for a split second. To get around this, we set the image source to `null` before setting the actual source in `OnBindingContextChange` method in our viewcell implementation. I have taken this logic out. 
  **This seemed to fix the issue with one user, but the other two no dice**
- I then installed a nuget package called `FFImageLoading` which helps out with image caching and memory allocating. Although, it seemed redundant considering we have a listview with caching strategy set to `recycle`, I felt it was worth a shot. **This seemed to fix the issue with one of the other users, but one still was unable to load images**
- I then changed the caching strategy of my listview to `retainelement` instead of `recycleelement`, surely I thought this was the culprit. **Both of the users who said the issue was fixed, still was able to load images. The third was STILL not able to**

Pretty much out of options here. I know that the external image sources are good, for it works fine on *most* devices. I can't really wrap my head around what the issue could be. Does anyone have any insight on this? Or any mechanism you can think of to diagnose this?

Comment: you're loading them from an external url?  If it only impacts a few users I would suspect a networking problem.

Comment: Our old grid these users seemed to get them fine though. I mean it's the weirdest thing. Image has a source, we set the source and the image doesn't load. Really having a hard time wrapping my head around what could POSSIBLY be the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue with loading remote images. It turns out that one of the servers in the server farm was down, and the user was hitting the downed server. Once I brought the server back up I noticed that the images didn't copy over to the server. After copying them over the issue was resolved. If this is not the case; Did you try to reproduce the issue using the same device the user has?

Comment: We have 6K users all over the country/world. I do not have access to their phones unfortunately.